# removeEventListener doesn't work inside useEffect logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener

In ReactJS, if I have a `useEffect` checking for an `observer` like this:

```
// ...observer code here

useEffect(() => {

    function handleParallax() {
        let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
        items.forEach(item => {
            let distance = (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset),
                distanceFinal = item.parentNode.offsetTop - distance,
                multi = 45;
            console.log((distanceFinal * multi)/500);
            let calc = `translate3d(0, calc(370px + ${((distanceFinal * multi)/500)}px), 0)`;
            item.setAttribute('style',
                `transform: ${calc};
                -ms-transform: ${calc};
                -webkit-transform: ${calc};`
            );
        });
    }

    if (isIntersecting) {
        console.log('enter')
        window.addEventListener('scroll', handleParallax, true)
    }else{
        console.log('exit')
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleParallax, true);
    }
}, [isIntersecting]);
```

the `removeEventListener` doesn't work, in fact I receive a console log in browser of the enter/exit state of the observed area, but the console log inside the `handleParallax` function still logs as I scroll outside of the observer bounds, why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `handleParallax` function outside the component (which is possible since it doesn't use any internal component data), so that the same reference will be passed to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

Comment: not possible, it uses both document and window, which throw error in React if used outside a useEffect or useLayoutEffect

Comment: @NathanBernard The `handleParallax` function would still be used inside the `useEffect`, not outside. And there is no requirement that `document` and `window` only be accessed inside a `useEffect`. Is there a specific error you are getting with this solution?

Comment: sorry I misread thought you meant outside of the useEffect, outside the component works. I thought it has the same error of using window inside the component but outside a useEffect, instead outside the component works, thank you